# Why does the value in classRosterArray seemingly persist after I delete in the 'remove' function?

Tags: c++, pointers

in Main.cpp I call the add function which adds student objects to classRosterArray

```
roster.add(id, firstName, lastName, email, age, daysInCourse1, daysInCourse2, daysInCourse3, degree);
roster.remove("A3");
```

Relevant part of add function in Roster.cpp:

```
Student* student = new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age, degreeprogram, daysInCourses);

classRosterArray[numberOfStudentsAdded] = student;
```

In the 'remove' function a studentID is passed in. If it matches a studentId in classRosterArray then that value is deleted:

```
void Roster::remove(string studentID) {   
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if  (classRosterArray[i]->getId() == studentID) {
                    cout << "removed: " << studentID << endl;
                    delete classRosterArray[i];
                    printAll();
                    return;
                }
            else {
                cout << "The student with the ID: " << studentID << " was not found\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

edited to add in printAll() function

```
void Roster::printAll() {
        //prints a complete tab-separated list of student data, each data point indented (tab)
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            classRosterArray[i]->print();
        }
    }
```

But printAll() still prints all values regardless. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why are you using strcmp for c++ strings. anyway if you want == you have to test if strcmp returns 0, read its man page. but reall just do `...getID() == studentID`

Comment: thanks @pm100, I updated it and it looks a lot cleaner. It still prints the student object that matches that studentID however.

Comment: ` delete classRosterArray[i];` is not how you remove something from an array

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> delete classRosterArray[i];
> ```

After this line, `classRosterArray[i]` will be an invalid pointer (or null if it was before deletion). After this, you call `printAll()` which contains:

> ```
> classRosterArray[i]->print();
> ```

Here, you attempt to access an object through an invalid pointer. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> What am I doing wrong?

You are indirecting through an invalid pointer. That's wrong. Don't do that. To fix the program, remove the call to `printAll();` from `remove`.

Another thing you're doing wrong: You unnecessarily use bare owning pointers. Don't do that. Probably, `classRosterArray` should actually be `std::vector<Student>`. Or, since you're doing search based on a key, perhaps `std::unordered_set<std::string, Student>` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

`delete classRosterArray[i];` is not how you remove something from an array

you do not show how that array is implemented. I hope it is a `std::vector`, if so you need to use `erase`

I also hope that the contents of the arrray are `std::unique_ptr`

but way better would be to put the objects in a `std::map` with studentID being the key

Comment: `is not how you remove something from an array` To expand on this: There is no way to remove something from an array. The number of elements in an array doesn't change through the lifetime of the array.

Comment: @eerorika - you can shuffle the elements down